# Boolean equation properties question

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Usually in calculus subjects multiplying two sides of an equation by a variable is "correct" and can be applied to get from an expression "X" to another expression "Y". If the first expression is correct, the second one should be too. Adding a certain number to both sides is also valid, too.

Is this same method correct in boolean algebra? Say I want to prove that this expression:

a) x + y = y

is equivalent to:

b) ~x + y = 1

I would have to prove two things: first, that if a) is true, then b) is *always* true. And second, that if b) is true, then a) is *always* true, too.

**Suppose a) is correct**

x + y = y -> Multiply both sides by ~y and get:

~y(x+y) = ~y*y -> Apply distribution and complementary's axiom:

~y*x + ~y*y = 0 -> Apply complementary's axiom again:

~y*x + 0 = 0 -> Apply DeMorgan's law:

~(y+ ~x) = 0 -> Put complementary on both sides:

y + ~x = 1

Until now, are all these steps correct and not made up fallacies?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want to show that the expression $x+y = y$ is true **iff** the expression $\lnot x + y = 1$.

One way is to make truth tables for all values of $x,y$ and check that the tables are the same (they are).

Here is an algebraic proof:

Suppose $x+y = y$, then $x+\lnot x + y = y+\lnot x$ and since $x+\lnot x = 1$ we
have $1 = y+\lnot x$.

Now suppose $\lnot x + y = 1$, then $\lnot y(\lnot x + y) = \lnot y$ and hence
$\lnot y\lnot x  = \lnot y$. Now invert both sides and use De Morgan to get
$x + y = y$.

Comment: Yep! That seems like a good way to prove that they are in fact the same.
Do you know if it is possible to multiply both sides of an equation by the same variable to prove certain properties?

Comment: @user3448229: I added an algebraic proof.

Comment: Thank you so much! Short, direct proof and well explained.